# selectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I have a class that allows a user to add entries to a server-side table. Everything works correctly until I attempt to refresh the `UITableView` with the new data. I make a server call to get the new dataset, use it to refresh the `NSArray` that is the data source for the table, and then attempt to reload the table. Here is the method that is called when the data comes back from the server:

```
- (void) logEntriesRefreshed : (NSNotification *) notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"log_entries_refreshed"
                                                  object:nil];

    NSLog(@"returned from log entries fetch");

    _logEntriesArray = [LogEntriesDataFetcher getLogEntriesArray];
    [_tableView reloadData];

    _activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    NSLog(@"log entries array count: %lu", [_logEntriesArray count]);

    [_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
                            animated:NO
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

It's this last line that is the problem. I want to programmatically select the first row in the table (there has to be at least one, since I just added a row). But it appears that this line never executes. Note this method, which should go next:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"here");

    UITableViewCell *previousCell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_previousIndexPath];
    previousCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    previousCell.textLabel.textColor = [SharedVisualElements primaryFontColor];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [SharedVisualElements secondaryFontColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [SharedVisualElements primaryFontColor];

    _previousIndexPath = indexPath;

    // get the file attributes for the cell just selected
    _currentEntry = (LogEntry *)[_logEntriesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"array count: %lu", (unsigned long)[_logEntriesArray count]);
    NSLog(@"current entry: %ld", (long)[indexPath row]);

    _isExistingEntry = YES;
    _arrayPositionOfEntryBeingEdited = [indexPath row];

    [self initializeValues];
    [self initializeObjects];
    [self captureStartingValuesForStateMachine];
}
```

I have break points set on the `selectRowAtIndexPath` line and also on the first `NSLog(@"here")` line in `didSelectRow...`. I get to the `selectRowAtIndexPath` line but never to the `didSelectRow` method. My console output is consistent with that:

```
returned from log entries fetch
log entries array count: 7
```

and that is the end of it. Nothing from the `didSelectRow...` method. There are no errors thrown, either.

What am I missing. Seems pretty straightforward, but nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: Is the `UITableViewDelegate` set?

Comment: @vadian - yes, it is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Apple's documentation, calling `selectRowAtIndexPath` will NOT invoke the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:).

> Calling this method does not cause the delegate to receive a
>   **tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:** or
>   **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** message, nor does it send
>   UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notifications to observers.

To specifically invoke the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, use the following code:

```
[[tableView delegate] tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked. I guess I learned something new today. It makes me wonder what the point of the `selectRowAtIndexPath` method is, if it isn't to select the row at an index path...  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Same here! Took me sometime to understand this. Glad I could be of help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: selectRowAtIndexPath will show the row selected and calling delegate will actually select that row.  So to programatically show the selection of row, both the method are necessary.